# EFS mount target

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-efs

I am building this env:
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-refarch-wordpress

Could you please tell me for what I need EFS mount target? I can't understand. For now, I set up 5 WordPress instances in 3 availability zones. And now I have only 1 mount target. What a mount target should do? Could you please explain it to me?

All WordPress instances are auto mounted to EFS. What job mounts target instances?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you can you EFS only for 2 or 3 mount target. If you have more than 3 mount targets you have to create instances in every availability zones, connect your EFS for this mount target machine and after that connect your for exaplple web servers to mount target machine. Sorry for my english. Good luck